ELOGIN error occurred while trying to connect to MSSQL using Windows Authentication
I tried to connect with Windows Authentication and I didn't give user name and password. But error says "login failed for user ' '". Because of this I am thinking code trying to connect with SQL Server authentication.
Here is my code:
const config = {
  server: "D15\\SQLEXPRESS",
  database: "DBToDo",
  port: 1433,
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
    trustServerCertificate: true
  }
};

sql.connect(config, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection error:', err);
    console.log('Error info:', err);
    
  } else {
    console.log('connected!');
    
    
    const request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('SELECT * FROM Tasks', (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('query error:', err);
        console.log('error info:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('query output:', result.recordset);
      }
    });
  }
});

originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

Have you tried reading the mssql documentation yet? You need to use msnodesqlv8 if you want to use Windows authentication.

Please don't use images for errors, post the error as text.

I tried msnodesqlv8 already. I solved when I created config object in diffirent .js file.
module.exports = {
server: "D15\\SQLEXPRESS",
database: "DBToDo",
port: 1433,
driver: "msnodesqlv8",
options: {
  trustedConnection: true,
}

};
